# How do I display a Panel when selecting a word in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

When I select or double-click on a word in the `RichTextBox`, a panel should **appear above this word** (This `panel` is initially hidden and appears when the word is highlighted). When I remove the selection, the `panel` should disappear.

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
       panel1.Visible = true;
    else
       panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to make the panel appear above the selected word?

Comment: You may want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11389601/3775798) for an idea on how to get position information of selected words for positioning your Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your changes, you need a custom control to achieve this.
Set your custom location for that, another problem might be the `z-index` (priority) of your `Control` (here: `buttonOverlay`). With `buttonOverlay.BringToFront()`, you'll set it to the front.

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
    {
        Point relativePoint = rTxtBxSelectionTester.GetPositionFromCharIndex(rTxtBxSelectionTester.SelectionStart);
        int txtBsPosX = relativePoint.X + rTxtBxSelectionTester.Location.X; 
        int txtBxPosY = relativePoint.Y + rTxtBxSelectionTester.Location.Y - this.buttonOverlay.Size.Height; 
        relativePoint = new Point(txtBsPosX, txtBxPosY);
        this.buttonOverlay.Location = relativePoint;
        this.buttonOverlay.Visible = true;
        this.buttonOverlay.BringToFront();          
    }
    else
    {
        this.buttonOverlay.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

To add the custom `Control` add the following code to your `Form` constructor:

```
this.buttonOverlay = new FormattingOverlay(this);
this.Controls.Add(this.buttonOverlay);
this.buttonOverlay.Visible = false;`
```

The `FormattingOverlay`is a class that inherits from `UserControl`:

```
public partial class FormattingOverlay : UserControl
{

    public FormattingOverlay(Form1 mainForm)
    {
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnBold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox rTxtBx = mainForm.rTxtBxSelectionTester;
        rTxtBx.SelectionFont = new Font(rTxtBx.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        rTxtBx.SelectionStart = rTxtBx.SelectionStart + rTxtBx.SelectionLength;
        rTxtBx.SelectionLength = 0;
        rTxtBx.SelectionFont = rTxtBx.Font;
    }
}
```

The whole sample project can be found [via this link.](http://blog.abouchleih.com/wp-content/uploads/SOQuestion44313656new2.7z)

Comment: There should not be words on this panel. I need to have buttons on this panel.

Comment: In this panel, the text formatting buttons should be located. If the user selects a word, then this panel appears with editing buttons of the selected word or line.

Comment: I made some changes to the code, take a look at it, also created a new sample project.

Comment: It looks great, but how to raise the panel above? The panel should be above the selected word.

Comment: `int txtBsPosX = relativePoint.X + rTxtBxSelectionTester.Location.X;
int txtBxPosY = relativePoint.Y + rTxtBxSelectionTester.Location.Y - buttonOverlay.Size.Height;
relativePoint = new Point(txtBsPosX, txtBxPosY);`

Comment: It does not work all the same. Can you add this to the sample project?

Comment: Since you use `Dock:Fill`, your `RichTextBox1` location is always (0,0). You have to use the `panel2.Size.Width` to get your overlay to the right position. Please create new questions for other issues, since this answer is complete.