# Place the button in front of the string

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How to place the `button` in front of the line where the marker is set?
The `button` should be placed just before the string. If the user moves the marker, then the `button` will move to another string. As in the picture.

At the moment, the `button` is displayed opposite the line where the `click` occurred.

```
        private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        buttonaddmenu.Visible = true;

        int index = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
        buttonaddmenu.Visible = true;
        int x = richTextBox1.Location.X - 10;
        int y = 25;

        for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            buttonaddmenu.Location = new Point(3, Cursor.Position.Y - 170);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by "in front of" and "opposite" the line. Can you explain exactly?

Comment: Where is the expected position? Where is "in front of the line"?

Comment: I also don't understand why you have a for loop where the inner instruction is always the same

Comment: Should the button display on mouse hover on a line or on click of a line?

Comment: No. The button should be displayed where the marker is.

Comment: We had exactly the same question a few weeks before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313656/how-do-i-display-a-panel-when-selecting-a-word-in-a-richtextbox/44313879#44313879 Instead of the overlay use a button instead.

Comment: Is the animation what you have or what you want???

Comment: I have seen that. This is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the new position based on button size (my button size 21, 23) by increasing or decreasing the x and y (eg:locationOnForm.X-20) try this :

```
      private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        var pos = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
        Point locationOnForm = richTextBox1.FindForm().PointToClient(richTextBox1.Parent.PointToScreen(richTextBox1.Location));
        Point newLocation = new Point(locationOnForm.X-20,
                          pos.Y + locationOnForm.Y);
        button2.Location = newLocation;
        }
```

**Update**

```
        Point locationOnForm = panel1.FindForm().PointToClient(panel1.Parent.PointToScreen(richTextBox1.Location));
```

Comment: But how to place the button opposite the string? The button should only move vertically.

Comment: Sorry, there is one more question. How do I display this button on the panel, and not on the form?